# Analyse interaction/moderators first and then adjust for confounding

Tags: interaction, glmm, confounding

In my research I am interested in subgroup analyses. 
I am looking at a general association between two variables (environment and health outcome) with interaction terms (personal factors, which are the subgroups). 
I want to do first the interactions and then correct for potential confounders (instead of the other way around), what is your take on it?

Comment: How are you going to "correct" for potential confounders?

Comment: Please say more.  You may want to visit our Help Center, e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi user2974951, thanks for your question! First I will look at whether the variables are both associated to the outcome and independent variable and then I will insert them one per one in the GLMM and look at whether AIC decreases.